# How to insert json values into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I recive this JSON from a site

```
https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=1d85872a9b324abcabb2aea5ab397605
```

and it looks like this.

```
{
  "disclaimer": "Exchange rates...",
  "license": "Data sourced from various providers...",
  "timestamp": 1433782861,
  "base": "USD",
  "rates":
  {
      "BWP": 10.075038,
      "CHF": 0.934077,
      "CNY": 6.188018,
      "EUR": 0.890331,
      "GBP": 0.653896,
      "ZMW": 7.248788
   }
}
```

How can I insert, or rather periodically update a MySQL database replacing previous values using PHP, MySQL  with this structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rate` (
  `currency_` varchar(10) NOT NULL Primary key,
  `value_` decimal(10,5) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
include('con.php'); //http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

//get the json
$json = file_get_contents('https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=1d85872a9b324abcabb2aea5ab397605');

//decode json, in to an array
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);

//iterate over the array
foreach($decoded['rates'] as $currency => $rate){
    $rates[] = "('" . $currency . "', '" . $rate . "')";
}

//query, just connect once
 $sql =  "INSERT INTO `lol`.`rate` (`currency_`, `value_`) VALUES " . implode(",",$rates) . "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value_ = VALUES(value_)";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo 'Record created successfully<br>';
} else {
    echo $sql . '"<br>"' . mysqli_error($con);
};    
?>
```

EDIT: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

con.php:

```
<?php
//use your connection data here
$user = "";
$pass = "";
$host = "";
$dbdb = "";

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbdb);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this at least be decent enough to give some feedback about it.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\concurency\son.php on line 22

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\concurency\son.php on line 25

INSERT INTO `rate` (`currency_`, `value_`) VALUES ( 'UGX', '3099.433333' ),
( 'USD', '1' )ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value_ = VALUES(value_)"

Comment: @AbelPuleChilungu I included con.php that file contains my connection data. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

Comment: wow thanx PHPhil this worked 1 time,  your the best

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to fill a field `currency_` and a field `value_`. With your posted JSON and assuming, `$db` is a MySQLi connection link:

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);
foreach($json['rates'] as $k => $v){
    $db->query("DELETE FROM `rate` WHERE `currency_` = '" . $db->real_escape_string($k) . "'");
    $db->query("INSERT INTO `rate` (`currency_`, `value_`) VALUES ('" . $db->real_escape_string($k) . "', " . floatval($v) . ")");
}
```

If you just want to save the array in database, you can save it as JSON or can serialize it:

```
$arr = serialize(json_decode($result, true));
```

---

Just update:

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);
foreach($json['rates'] as $k => $v)
    $db->query("UPDATE `rate` SET `value_` = " . floatval($v) . " WHERE `currency_` = '" . $db->real_escape_string($k) . "'");
```

Comment: Why would you delete and the insert, what is wrong with an update

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Do you know if the entry yet exists? :-) Of course, you can do just an update instead ;-) I want that code to work for the purposed thing first :-)

Comment: See question, **or rather periodically update a MySQL database**

Comment: yes I simply just want to update into mysql database from that table created. you can assume the currency is already entered but the value is what needs periodic update from that json received .

Comment: wow thanx PHPhil this worked 1 time, your the best